# Android mosaic layout (or view)

Tags: android, layout, imageview, mosaic

How can I implement the layout (or view) that will place images most rationally in 3:4, 1:1 or 4:3 area. Images order is important; images may be cropped. For example:

2 tall pictures:

[image: 2 tall pictures]

5 wide pictures:

[image: 5 wide pictures]

...and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment your question to say that your examples don't appear in your question. But I would like to propose using this library [AndroidMosaicLayout](https://github.com/adhamenaya/AndroidMosaicLayout) to display your images in mosaic pattern.

Actually this library enables using 90 different patterns consists of 4 basic shapes **(small square, big square which is 4 small squares, vertical rectangle and horizontal rectangle, both rectangle consists of 2 small square)**.

You have to define the pattern you need using an array describing that pattern, this array of size 8, so each pattern the basic gird forming it consists of 8 small squares.

For example, if you want to get the following patter:

```
 ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
|           |           |                       |
|           |   img 2   |         img 3         |
|   vert.   |   small   |   horiz.      horiz.  |
|           |           |                       |
|   img 1   | --------- | --------- | --------- |
|           |                       |           |
|           |         img 4         |   img 5   |
|   vert.   |   horiz.      horiz.  |   small   |
|           |                       |           |
 ----------  ----------- ----------- -----------
```

You need to define pattern by setting the role for each square of the main 8 square shaping the entire pattern. So for this shape the pattern will be like this:

```
BLOCK_PATTERN pattern[] = { 
        BLOCK_PATTERN.VERTICAL, BLOCK_PATTERN.SMALL, BLOCK_PATTERN.HORIZONTAL, BLOCK_PATTERN.HORIZONTAL,
        BLOCK_PATTERN.VERTICAL, BLOCK_PATTERN.HORIZONTAL, BLOCK_PATTERN.HORIZONTAL, BLOCK_PATTERN.SMALL 
};
```

Comment: How can we set orientation from vertical to horizontal, there is no documentation about changing orientation in this library?